# R - create indicator column for whether a value appears within a group

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df with a set of IDs that may appear multiple times with a different Status for each row. I need to create a 0/1 indicator column for whether Status "B" ever appears for that ID. B_appears shows my desired result.

I have done something *kind of* related by creating a "Count" column that counts the number of times the Status listed in that row appears for that ID. But I can't figure out how to create the indicator variable that is specifically related to Status "B."

This is how I created the "Count" column, fwiw.
df <- ddply(df),.(ID,Status), transform, Count = length(ID))

Thanks in advance!

| ID | Status | Count | B_appears |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | B | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | A | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | B | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we group by 'ID', get the `Count` column with group size (`n()`) and the 'B_appears' by creating a logical vector check whether 'B' is `%in%` the `Status` and convert the logical to binary (`+` or `as.integer`)

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(Count = n(), 
        B_appears = +('B' %in% Status)) %>%
       # or may also create B_appears as
       # B_appears = +(any(Status %in% 'B'))) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 × 4
     ID Status Count B_appears
  <int> <chr>  <int>     <int>
1     1 A          1         0
2     2 A          3         1
3     2 B          3         1
4     2 B          3         1
5     3 A          2         1
6     3 B          2         1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), Status = c("A", 
"A", "B", "B", "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```